# How to use dates in this code for y axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, graphing

The person who made this had used dates in the second graph. I was wondering how would dates be used with the scipy.signal.argrelextrema function.

With this code it doesn't do anything it prints out an empty array for peak_x and peak_y:

```
data_y = np.array('2015-07-04', dtype=np.datetime64) + np.arange(25)
```

Here's the link for the original code:
https://openwritings.net/pg/python/python-find-peaks-and-valleys-chart-using-scipysignalargrelextrema

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg') # Bypass the need to install Tkinter GUI framework

from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate random data.
data_x = np.arange(start = 0, stop = 25, step = 1, dtype='int')
data_y = np.array('2015-07-04', dtype=np.datetime64) + np.arange(25) #edited part

# Find peaks(max).
peak_indexes = signal.argrelextrema(data_y, np.greater)
peak_indexes = peak_indexes[0]

# Find valleys(min).
valley_indexes = signal.argrelextrema(data_y, np.less)
valley_indexes = valley_indexes[0]


# Plot main graph.
(fig, ax) = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data_x, data_y)

# Plot peaks.
peak_x = peak_indexes
peak_y = data_y[peak_indexes]
ax.plot(peak_x, peak_y, marker='o', linestyle='dashed', color='green', label="Peaks")
print(peak_x,peak_y)

# Plot valleys.
valley_x = valley_indexes
valley_y = data_y[valley_indexes]
ax.plot(valley_x, valley_y, marker='o', linestyle='dashed', color='red', label="Valleys")


# Save graph to file.
plt.title('Find peaks and valleys using argrelextrema()')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.savefig('argrelextrema.png')
```

Here's the example how it would work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the xticks method. See below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names = [str(i) for i in range(20)]

x_data = [x for x in range(20)]
y_data = [x for x in range(20)]

plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
plt.xticks(x_data, label=names)
plt.show()
```

What this does is use an integer between 1-19 cast as a string as the label for the axis X.

Except in your case you want to swap out the names for datatime objects cast to strings. For the xticks, the x_data element prescribes where the ticks will be. You may use any interval of points so long as they are within the bounds of the xdata.

In your case, replace:

```py
data_y = np.array('2015-07-04', dtype=np.datetime64) + np.arange(25)
```

with

```py
data_y_ticks = np.array('2015-07-04', dtype=np.datetime64) + np.arange(25) 

data_y = [i for i, _ in enumerate(data_y_ticks.tolist())]
```

then plot as follows:

```py
plt.plot(data_y, x_data)
plt.xticks(data_y, label=data_y_ticks)
plt.show()
```

Just a heads-up, your X and Y axis names are flipped in your code. I did not correct this in my example, however did interchange their locations in the plot to make the plot make sense.